# curtain.js not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cloned an instance of the curtain.js package, and noticed enclosed example file works on FF, but not Chrome.

I get the following error on Console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
```

I am not sure what the error is about.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Unfortunately, curtain.js hasn't been maintained in several years.  I don't know what this particular error is about but it's not likely to be a stable package.